# iOS 7 UIWebView inconsistent Loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

In my project I have 2 UIWebViews that are IBOutlets and created in the main.storyboard.

One I load by calling a method on ViewDidAppear. It appears perfectly and hits all it's delegate methods. We will call this ViewA

The other is supposed to be Hidden and appear and load when the user taps a button. We will call this ViewB. But once I submit the request, nothing happens, none of the delegate methods get called.

ViewA loads perfectly. If I try to load ViewB on ViewDidAppear, it also loads.

EDIT: Moving the ViewA and ViewB load method calls to the ButtonPress method calls both successfully.

EDIT: Code

```
-(void)loadCarouselWebView //ViewA 
{
    NSString *urlString     = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[JSONReader sharedInstance] baseURLToLoad:environmentURLPublicKey],[[JSONReader sharedInstance] URLToLoad:kCarouselURLkey]];

    NSURL *url              = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    self.carouselWebView.delegate = self;

    [self.carouselWebView loadRequest: requestObj];

}
-(void)loadFullWebView:(int)index //ViewB
{
    NSString *gameURL;

    switch (index) {
        case 1:
            gameURL = game1Constant;
            break;
        case 2:
            gameURL = game2Constant;
            break;
        case 3:
            gameURL = game3Constant;
        default:
            break;
    }

    NSString *urlString     = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[JSONReader sharedInstance] baseURLToLoad:environmentURLKey],[[JSONReader sharedInstance] URLToLoad:gameURL]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    self.fullWebView.delegate = self;

    [self.fullWebView loadRequest: requestObj];


}

- (IBAction)gameButtonPushed:(id)sender {
    [[self fullWebView] setHidden:NO];
    [[self backNavButton] setHidden:NO];

    [self loadFullWebView:[sender tag]];
    [self loadCarouselWebView];//Added for debugging
}
```

EDIT: ONLY Loading ViewB on button tap works. If I add Load ViewA on ViewDidAppear then ViewB will not load.

Comment: Please add your code so that we can help you find your mistake.

Comment: Added code and new information.

Comment: And you're sure that those web views exist? I.e. if you call `NSLog()` on them you get a valid object that's a subview within the window?

Comment: Yeah I NSLogged it and it's fine:
    Fullscreen Instance <UIWebView: 0x156736f0; frame = (0 0; 320 434); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x15669060>>

Comment: And the `NSURLRequest` objects? Are they non-nil too?

Comment: Yeah the Request is fine, I can even hit the URL through my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a surprise twist, there is nothing wrong with the UIWebView.
It was my fault for not reading the code carefully enough.

Someone coded a one time counter into the shouldStartLoadingRequest delegate method that I missed. So only one request was allowed to load.

Thats like 2 days burned there, great stuff! >:E